# Integer in for loop acting weird

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

In the for loop i wont increment. The input I want is X++ or X-- and I want to change the value of x accordingly. But when I enter these inputs it loops back but the value of i isn't changed. However if I enter random strings i increases. AND i's starting value is shown as 0, but i defined it as 1. I'm really confused help me out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char a[3];
    int b,x=0;
    scanf("%d",&b);
    for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",a);
        if(a[1]=='+')
        {
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            x--;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",x);

}
```

Comment: "AND i's starting value is shown as 0" in the debuger? In your code there is no way to see `i`s value

Comment: Remember; array indices start at `0`. An array of `3` elements has valid values at index `0`, `1` & `2`. Index `3` is out of bounds.

Comment: If you're trying to store "X++" in the `a` buffer, then you will need it to be *at least* 4 characters long: `char a[4];` (to make room for the required 'nul'-terminator). As it stands, you're most likely overrunning the buffer, causing undefined behaviour (at which point, all bets are off and the code can do pretty much anything).

Comment: the problem isn't the array. And I put some printf's in the code to check and i's value is 0 even in the beggining of the for loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It appears OP is checking the *second* character, in a string like "X++" or "X--" - which is `a[1]`.

Comment: I dont really know much about c++ arrays but I'll give it a shot. Time to find out what buffers are.

Comment: Yep adrians solution works. Thanks people.